# Dynamic variable with regEx

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm building a script that tests if a variable is present in an object. To do that I use a regEx to test if that specific name is present in the object.

The problem I'm facing is that the JSON response is sometimes translated in German or Spanish. 
So in below case I want to test `spec.title` for the name `Length (mm)`. This title also can be `Länge (mm)` and `Longitud (mm)`.

In my project there's an already build in translation function called `getAjaxTranslation('string')`
So this `getAjaxTranslation('length')` will return the translated string for length.

So my question is how can I use `getAjaxTranslation('length')` in below code to test?

So what I tried is:

```
reLength = '/'+ getAjaxTranslation('length') + '/i' //just to try
reLength = "'+ getAjaxTranslation('length') + '";
reLength = getAjaxTranslation('length')
```

Above tries give errors like `reLength.test is not a function` etc. So probably I'm working with wrong string/variables or doing something really wrong. I still have problems with those regExs...

Any help greatly appreciated!

Full code:

```
var data = {
  "product": {
    "specs": {
      "231638": {
        "id": 231638,
        "title": "Length (mm)",
        "value": "1200"
      },
      "231641": {
        "id": 231641,
        "title": "Width (mm)",
        "value": "800"
      },
      "231644": {
        "id": 231644,
        "title": "Height (mm)",
        "value": "144"
      } //etc etc
    }
  }
};

var length = 0, width = 0, height = 0,
  reLength = /length/i,
  reWidth = /width/i,
  reHeight = /height/i;
$.each(data.product.specs, function (specId, spec) {
  if (reLength.test(spec.title))
    length = spec.value;
  else if (reWidth.test(spec.title))
    width = spec.value;
  else if (reHeight.test(spec.title))
    height = spec.value;
});
```

Comment: you are only creating strings not [regular expression objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Above tries give errors like reLength.test is not a function etc.

`test` is a method of `RegExp` object, make it

```
reLength =  new RegExp( getAjaxTranslation('length') , "i" )
```

Or use `match` instead of `test`, for example

```
reLength =  getAjaxTranslation('length'); //no need to make a regexp object
!!spec.title.match(reLength)
```

or

```
reLength =  getAjaxTranslation('length'); 
spec.title.includes(reLength) //use includes
```

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan match will either return an array-link output or null, so `match` itself should help as well.

Comment: True, although using `!!` to coerce the type seems unnecessary when a simple `test()` call would work. Also note that I removed my downvote, however your first line - `test is a method of RegExp function` - is incorrect.  `test()` is a method of the Regexp object, no matter if it's create explicitly (as in your example) or through literal notation (as in the OPs snippet). The important part of your solution is using the constructor with the concatenated string pattern.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Agree, I was trying to suggest that OP need not make a regex object and simply use the `getAjaxTranslation('length')`. I will update the answer accordingly

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I corrected this *test is a method of RegExp object* as well. This is what I had meant as well earlier.

Comment: @gurvinder372: Ok interesting. Will `match` also work when some `spec.titles` are almost the same? So let's say these two spec titles: `length` and `length (mm)` for example? Or is match used to exactly match whole string?

Comment: Yes and also `includes` for that matter.

Comment: @gurvinder372: Ok I will test that.... I tried your first solution that works perfectly. So I will accept your answer for sure. But I will test your other two solutions as well.... Thx for the insights, I really need to learn those regExp... They just won't keep hanging in my head ;)

Comment: @Meules Sure, glad to help.